# Find principal ideals a, b in Z[√−6]

Tags: number-theory

Find principal ideals a, b in Z[√−6] such that
a<2,√−6>=b<3,√−6>.

Comment: I do like the question, but in a case like this, you should “thicken” your question by telling people what you know, where you are in your number-theoretical training, and what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
Since the norm of $\langle2,\sqrt{-6}\,\rangle$ is $2$, and the norm of $\langle3,\sqrt{-6}\,\rangle$ is $3$, you’ll need elements whose norms are in the ratio $3:2$. I think any pair of elements of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}\,]$ with this property should do it.